# Sudden spike in CPU temperatures

Tags: macos, temperature

My Macbook Pro 13" early 2011 has been running fairly cool for the last 4 months, about an average of 32-40C. However, within the last few days, the average temp has gone to an average of 45 - 52C, with the highs being in the 90s! I have tried using SMC fan control, but even at max my temps don't go below 45. I don't run intensive applications. I have been watching my CPU load for weeks as a hobby, and I know that I'm not running anything to put this kind of load. What's going on?

Comment: Does it seem hotter to you? Could it be that the temperature sensor is not reporting accurately any longer? If you turn the machine off and let it cool do you find immediately on reboot that the reported temperature is unusually high? Are you using it on a different surface than usual?

Comment: I keep my computer in the same place all the time. I didn't get a chance to see the temp when I turned it on, but it was averaging around 45C again. Once, when I woke it from sleeping, it was around 35, but jumped back up to 45 almost immediately.

Comment: Do not forget the surrounding temperature.

Comment: The temperature in my house is fairly constant.

Comment: I'll echo @AllInOne - does the machine seem hotter (to the touch) than before?  One idea: perhaps some dust has built up in your fans & heatsink, and so the cooling isn't as effective as previously.

Comment: @Ashley It does not feel hotter to the touch. I am hoping taking apart my PC to clean the fan would be a last resort, as I have found notebooks to be infuriatingly complex.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the thermal mass it is not possible to have temperature spikes.

If that is the case please verify the software you are using to get the temperature readings.

Also please consider that the conversion Algorithm from temperature diodes readout requires calibration, that in your case was probably not done.

Comment: I am currently using Temperature Monitor to monitor my CPU temperatures.

Comment: "it is not possible to have temperature spikes" mine goes from 60 degrees to 92 in 3 seconds according to the temp monitoring software I have. The fan kicks in a second later to a very high RPM, so seems legit.